# How can I add header to the following data that I am pulling from the machine learning database

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

This is the data that I am pulling from the web:

```
import requests
r=requests.get('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data')
print(r.text[0:200])
```

This is what prints:

> 39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical,
>   Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K 50,
>   Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-man

I want to add the following headers to the data so I can build a classifier.

```
col_names = ['age', 'work_class', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'marital_status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'capital_gain', 'capital_loss', 'hours_per_week', 'native_country', 'class']
```

...but I am having trouble getting the names into the data.

I am running my data on colab.research.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a built-in python data structure. For example an array of dicts in the pattern [{header1: value1, header2:value2, ...}, ...] where each dict represents a line.

csv readers from the standard library can help, for example DictReader: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Pandas can be a heavier approach with a lot of user tooling:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, names=col_names)
# Colab will auto pretty print a df if it is the last line of the cell like so
df.head()
```

In general, this is the approach I would expect to see in research/data science, where numpy/pandas is very popular.